# Azure Data Flows - can column names be set based on a non-header row's values

Tags: azure-data-factory

If I have an input text file and don't import the schema, because the header row is in not in the first row, is it possible to somehow detect the schema from somewhere in the file other than the header row i.e. a file with no header row but a row that could be used as a header further down the file:

| <No | Header | Row> |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 01/01/2020 | NULL |
| 345 | 01/01/2021 | 01/01/2022 |
| 456 | 01/01/2019 | NULL |
| AccNo | StartDate | EndDate |
| 678 | 01/01/2021 | 01/02/2022 |

Could be transformed to and sunk in this schema after further transformations to match the output schema:

| AccNo | StartDate | EndDate | DateofDeath |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 01/01/2020 | NULL | NULL |
| 345 | 01/01/2021 | 01/01/2022 | NULL |
| 456 | 01/01/2019 | NULL | NULL |
| 678 | 01/01/2021 | 01/02/2022 | NULL |

I can't define an input schema as it needs to be flexible to allow for changes and multiple files (with different columns) will use the same process. I will though know the output schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilize the `skipLineCount` property available in Copy activity source settings.

1. Select `firstRowAsHeader` property in dataset connection settings
2. Copy activity source settings, set `skipLineCount = 4` this will skip the first 4 rows
3. In the mapping section do import schemas.

Above approach can be used, but you will not get first 4 records.

You can also refer this [article](https://kromerbigdata.com/2019/09/28/adf-dynamic-skip-lines-find-data-with-variable-headers/)

Comment: Great link thanks - the article nails it!